# Why is the index.php file not showing up after creating a new project in Netbeans?

Tags: php, netbeans

Steps (in Apache Netbeans):

1. File -> New Project
2. Select **PHP** under Categories and **PHP application** under Projects
3. Click **Next** and enter the project name and location. Select **PHP 7.4** as the version.
4. Click **Next** and after Run As: select **PHP Built-in Web Server**
5. Click **Finish** (we are not using PHP Frameworks or Composer)

Expected Result: NetBeans will create the project with a single index.php file.

Actual Result: NetBeans created a project **but there is no index.php file inside**. It only has 2 folders (Source Files and Include Path) and these folders contain nothing. I have also tried to double-click these folders but nothing happens. -> [Click for screenshot of how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBRkr.jpg)

Note: Before creating the PHP project in NetBeans, I have configured NetBeans using these steps:

1. **Tools -> Options** and select **PHP**
2. On the **General** tab, next to PHP Interpreter, click the **Browse…** button, navigate to the folder where PHP files are saved, and select **php.exe**

I have searched the internet regarding this issue but nothing works so far. I truly appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was once plagued by this very same problem, assuming that your are using Linix, if yes; I was plagued by the same problem. I looked everywhere; I performed searches on a lot of sites. I came across this thread and I scrolled immediately at the bottom for the solution. No answer, there was no solution, not one reply. I was using XAMPP and my PHP file was not being displayed.

This is how I got my problem resolved on my accord.
I can almost bet and win that you have in Netbeans your source folder pointing somewhere inside your local directory instead of pointing to your Apache Server directory. Don't be quick at running over and have the source folder within Netbeans, point over to the Apache Server directory structure, since that directory currently is protected.

With XAMPP, we can start and stop Apache Server and MySQL, among other services. At this moment if you and change the source folder within NetBeans, under the properties option of your project, you will get an error in red letters towards the bottom of the properties page something to the effect that the Source folder chosen is protected, locked, or write protected.
Using XAMPP, the path to the directory is the following:
`/opt/lampp/htdocs/`

By the way, all of my paths start from the root to avoid confusion.

It has to point to `htdocs` since that is the location where the source files need to be stored or it will not work. I could be wrong but it is where the Apache server gets the files to display and sends it over to `/var/www/html/`  do not quote me on that.

The source files of your project need to be stored or point to the path
`/opt/lampp/htdocs/`.

I used the following commands to change the rights:

```
cd /opt/lampp
sudo chmod 777 htdocs -R
```

It would be best if you could only change the rights only to the directory `htdocs` you could change the rights to the whole path but that may open up a whole set of problems down the road or it may not.

In the terminal do a `ls` command and you will notice that `htdocs` has changed color. Now go to the properties page of your project within NetBeans to the following path: `/opt/lampp/htdocs/`

#### Example

Inside the Project Properties window, my Project Folder and Source Folder both have the same path. The name of the Project is TestPHPdemo so my path is the following in both fields, Project Folder and Source Folder:
`/opt/lampp/htdocs/TestPHPdemo`

For testing purposes, I created a simple PHP file that will print or echo the following message: "Success! It is now working."

Now go to your green Run button within NetBeans and you will see your PHP message display on your browser, "Success! It is now working." If your still an unbeliever, change your message to display on your browser: "He was right, it is working!"